# Silence "Query OK 0 row affected" output in mysql script

Tags: mysql, sql, database, message

I have a MySQL script that creates several stored procedures. I would like to silence the

```
"Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)"
```

message that appears when I run

```
source MY_SCRIPT.sql;
```

It becomes a long list and I sometimes forget to scroll up and check for syntax errors during development. Is there a way to silence this without silencing error messages? Thanks

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_silent

Comment: Did you try --silent ?

Comment: use silent mode: mysql -s

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I guess I was searching ineffectively. Is there a way to do it for individual queries instead of the whole interactive session?