# Log file for Data Imported from sample.sql file

Tags: mysql, linux, database, database-administration

I'm Using MySQL and importing data which is in sample.sql file like below

it contains create table queries and insert queries.

now i need output of each query in log file : 
Table created successfully.
1 row inserted successfully.

how to do that  ?
i'm using bellow command for importing

```
user$mysql -h host-name -u user-name -p < /path/user/sample.sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply redirect `stdin` and `stderr` to a file. E.g.:

```
mysql < sample.sql &> mylog
```

Comment: Try to run the command without redirecting first. Check the output. Then redirect both output streams to a file and check the file content. It should be the same message previously shown on the console.

Comment: that is my problem when i'm importing data just its not showing anything on command prompt but database is creating internally.I want to see that in log file database created successfully inserted successfully like that

Comment: Are you using -s? Check this post for details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296752/silence-query-ok-0-row-affected-output-in-mysql-script

Comment: No i'm not using silent i'm just running the command this command in Linux command prompt    $mysql -h host-name -u user-name -p < /path/user/sample.sql

Comment: Are you sure the file is created? Try putting the file under /tmp where you have write permissions. mysql -h host-name -u user-name -p < /path/user/sample.sql &> /tmp/mylog